# Wrong injection of $modalProvider dependency angujarjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to open a dialog box in angularjs using bootstrap but whenever i try i get this error while injecting the right dependencies.

```
.controller('login_ctrl', ['$scope','$http','$window','$modal','$log', function($scope,$http,$window,$modal,$log) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
            controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',

            //size: size,
            resolve: {
                user: function() {
                    return userData;
                },
                selectedProducts: function() {
                    return userData.selectedProducts;
                },
                products: function () {
                    //console.log($scope.selectedProducts);
                    return $scope.products; // get all available products
                }
            }
        });

}])
```

all the files js and css files are in the head section of my document

```
<link href="/spree/web/lib/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/spree.css">
<script src="/spree/web/lib//angularjs/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/spree/web/lib/angularjs/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script src="/spree/web/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/spree/web/js/controller.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
```

and this is how the start of the js looks like

```
angular.module('controller', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

when i preview i get this error in the console

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalProvider%20%3C-%20%24modal%20%3C-%20login_ctrl

Comment: I suggest you [read the fine manual](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal). The service name is `$uibModal`, not `$modal`

Comment: Actually it depends what version you are using http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/0.13.4/#/modal make sure you read the 2.5.0 docs as Phil states.

Comment: do you have a controller defined as 'ModalInstanceCtrl'?

Comment: The `$modal` is `undefined` in your login_ctrl, try to use cdn source file in your project [ui-bootstrap cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-bootstrap/)

Comment: @pedro OP is clearly using v2.5.0

Comment: @Maher OP **is** using the CDN link for angular-ui-bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

> In new version of `ui-bootstrap` all params and injections changes to `$uib*` for example for your question you have to use `$uibModal` instead `$modal` in your controller.

```
.controller('login_ctrl', ['$scope','$http','$window','$uibModal','$log', function($scope,$http,$window,$uibModal,$log) {

var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',

        //size: size,
        resolve: {
            user: function() {
                return userData;
            },
            selectedProducts: function() {
                return userData.selectedProducts;
            },
            products: function () {
                //console.log($scope.selectedProducts);
                return $scope.products; // get all available products
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In angular js manual bootstrapping should be the last line of your js file. Add this line to the end of your js file

```
angular.module('controller', ['ui.bootstrap'])
```

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass your controller's name as dependency in module.
`angular.module('controller', ['login_ctrl','ui.bootstrap']);`